# What is the maximum size limit supported by Picture Library?

Tags: picture-library

I need to upload some 100 GB of photos to a Picture Library. I need to know what is the maximum size (in GB) I can have for the library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The maximum file size you can upload is 2GB.  Any file over that size will not upload.  You can upload all 100GB of pictures as long as they aren't individually 2GB or larger.

Here is the TechNet guide on 2010 limitations, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx.

Comment: What is the maximum limit for the Picture Library? Is it 100 GB?

Comment: There isn't per se, if you follow the TechNet information, they say content databases should not exceed 200GB.  100GB is under their recommendations so it's fine.  They don't have limits on sizes of library content, just library metadata structure.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, there isn't no limit on the picture library size.  It will depend on the overall limit of the site collection(SC).  If you are using SharePoint Online, then SC limit could be up to 25TB.  However, you would need to consider the threshold of 5000 and the sync limit.

More details here: https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/SharePoint-Online-software-boundaries-and-limits-8f34ff47-b749-408b-abc0-b605e1f6d498

Answer (score 1):

I think you can upload it if your DB can accommodate the space.For performance reasons,There are some threshold limits on no of items. See here : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx#ListLibrary

For optimal performance, you should organize it properly(using views or index colums) if the no of photos are >5000

Comment: Thx.  
What is the maximum limit for the Picture Library? Is it 100 GB?